# Call a Kohana helper from cron (or any URL)

Tags: model-view-controller, cron, kohana

I need to call a Kohana helper (or any php MVC framework) from a Cron job.
How can I do this?
The server is Linux, so, I can only think of two possible solutions:
1- Open an URL from the cron job, which hits a controller and does what it has to do.
2- Call a Kohana controller without passing through the web server, but with the PHP CLI. (is that even possible? I don't think so, it might need the web server environment to work)

Know a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

with the kohana framework you can pass the "uri" as a command line parameter:

> /path/to/index.php controller/method/param

you might want to try that, you will definitely need a controller but you dont need to use wget or curl

Comment: That syntax is for K2, for K3 you need `php index.php --uri="uri/path"`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just curl or wget the URL?

Comment: I think this can work in many cases, however if your cron job takes a very long time to run, than maybe your curl will timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
lynx > /dev/null -dump "URL"
wget -q -O /dev/null "URL"
fetch -o /dev/null "URL"
curl -s -o /dev/null "URL"
```

just replace URL